# `MatrixFunction` is returning a cryptic error message about "the function `1`"

Tags: functions, matrix, bugs, linear-algebra, warning-messages

The "Possible Issues" section of the documentation for `MatrixFunction` lists several possible ways in which a call to `MatrixFunction` can fail or not have a well-defined answer, and it gives clear error messages for each. But I just called `MatrixFunction[Sqrt, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}]` and got the cryptic error message

StringForm::sfr: Item 1 requested in "Cannot compute the matrix function for the function `1`." out of range; 0 items available"

MatrixFunction::nosol: Cannot compute the matrix function for the function `1`.

This error mode is not discussed in the documentation for `MatrixFunction`. I understand why the function call should fail, since the matrix does not actually have a square root. But I don't understand this error message. Where is it getting "the function `1`" from? `1` is not a function.

Comment: Try `MatrixFunction[Power[#, 1/2] &, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}]` -- there seems to be a mathematical problem with the square-root function (that it does not have a power series expansion about the eigenvalue 0).

Answer (score 1):

That specific message being thrown is a bug, please report it.

On the other hand, consider the general formula for the matrix function of a *Jordan block* (see e.g. [this reference](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=mlOa7wPX6OYC&pg=PA557)):

```
MatrixFunction[f, {{x, 1}, {0, x}}]
   {{f[x], f'[x]}, {0, f[x]}}
```

Recalling that `Sqrt'[x] == 1/(2 Sqrt[x])` and that we are considering the value `x == 0`, you can immediately see why this evaluation is not supposed to work.